# InstallShield dynamic configuration from XML file

Tags: installshield

InstallShield includes the ability to modify an applications .config file via XML File Changes*... but what if you want to share configuration settings across multiple installation packages?

In our environment we deliver a WPF application and a WinForms application where one is a management console and the other is a data collection app (single installer where users selects what they want). We also ship an installer for the service layer used by both apps so the webservice endpoints will be different at each customer location. (Actual environment is a bit more complicated but the above is an example of the complexity)

Our direction is to create an XML file that has common configuration settings for both installers that includes the common settings, InstallShield reads these values and then updates the .config file of each application to point to the same endpoints. Anyone done this? Can this be done without using InstallScript or a Custom Action?

- Importing the xml configuration file into the XML File Changes area to read in every line from the config file and creates add requests via XPath for every line (ex. add[@key="IsMultiTouch" and @value="True"]). This seems less than ideal as I suspect it is just recreating the file where I want it to read in the current state of the file from the dev team and only modify values in appsettings during the installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[followUp]
Pulled values from an InstallShield dialog using CtrlGetText(), passed that data to my dll for inclusion in my apps config file. The resultant .config file entry included a large number of "�" sequences. 
Attempts to clean those up with InstallScript didn't work out well.
Ultimately had to clean them up inside the dll by flipping the XmlDocument into a string, performing a .Replace("�", "") on the string, loaded that into a XmlDocument (to ensure it was valid), and then saved it.
InstallShield != awesome.
[/followUp]

XML File changes does not appear to be a good direction so instead I wrote a custom action that fires after the the feature is installed. The custom action calls into a managed assembly that spins through the xml file applying changes to the applications .config file.

**Custom Action**

```
#define CO_APPCONFIG_DLL "MyCompany.InstallShield.AppConfig.dll"
#define CO_APPCONFIG_FQNAME "MyCompany.InstallShield.AppConfig.ConfigMgr"

#define CO_APPSETTINGS_NEW "MyApp_AppSettings.xml"
#define CO_APPSETTINGS_CONFIG "MyCompany.IOAnywhere.Dashboard.exe.config"
#define CO_APPSETTINGS_SECTION "CO_dashboard"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The Installed event is sent after the feature Dashboard
// is installed.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
export prototype Dashboard_Installed();
function Dashboard_Installed()
BOOL bResult;
OBJECT oAppConfig;
begin

try
    // Note: the configuration dll is in the support directory
    set oAppConfig = DotNetCoCreateObject(SUPPORTDIR ^ CO_APPCONFIG_DLL, CO_APPCONFIG_FQNAME, "");
catch
    MessageBox("Error Loading" + SUPPORTDIR ^ CO_APPCONFIG_DLL + ": " + Err.Number + " " + Err.Description, INFORMATION); 
    abort;
endcatch;

try
    // Note: the new configuration settings file should be in the same folder as the setup.exe
    bResult = oAppConfig.ConfigureSettings(CO_APPSETTINGS_NEW, TARGETDIR ^ CO_APPSETTINGS_CONFIG, CO_APPSETTINGS_SECTION);
catch
    MessageBox("Verify that the file " + CO_APPSETTINGS_NEW + " exists in the setup directory.  Error calling ConfigureSettings " + SUPPORTDIR ^ CO_APPCONFIG_DLL + " " + Err.Number + " " + Err.Description, INFORMATION);
endcatch;

end;
```

**Called DLL**

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

/// <summary>
/// Called by InstallShield Installer process to apply appSettings to an installed applications .config file
/// </summary>
namespace CO.InstallShield.AppConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ConfigMgr is the class that encapsulates functionality related to modifying a .config file
    /// </summary>
    public class ConfigMgr
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ConfigureSettings applies changes from a common xml file to the applications .config file
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Ensures required keys for the application are included in the .config file
        /// Applies common settings to the .config file
        /// Applies application specific settings to the .config file
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="configFilePath">Path to the xml file that has the setting that need to be applied</param>
        /// <param name="targetAppConfigPath">Path to the .config file for the appliction</param>
        /// <param name="targetAppName">Section in the xml file that has application specific settings</param>
        /// <returns>True if it was able to configure settings</returns>
        public bool ConfigureSettings(string configFilePath, string targetAppConfigPath, string targetAppName)
        {
            bool completed = false;

            try
            {
                XmlDocument configFileDoc = new XmlDocument();
                configFileDoc.Load(configFilePath);

                XmlDocument targetAppConfigDoc = new XmlDocument();
                targetAppConfigDoc.Load(targetAppConfigPath);

                // ensure the appSettings section exists
                AddRequiredSections(ref targetAppConfigDoc);

                // ensure all required keys exist in the target .config file
                AddRequiredKeys(configFileDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/" + targetAppName + "/requiredKeys"), ref targetAppConfigDoc);

                // loop through each key in the common section of the configuration file
                AddKeyValues(configFileDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/common/appSettings"), ref targetAppConfigDoc);

                // loop through each key in the app specific section of the configuration file - it will override the standard configuration
                AddKeyValues(configFileDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/" + targetAppName + "/appSettings"), ref targetAppConfigDoc);

                // save it off
                targetAppConfigDoc.Save(targetAppConfigPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                completed = true;
            }
            return completed;
        }
        private void AddRequiredSections(ref XmlDocument targeAppConfigDoc)
        {
            // Ensure the target .config file has an appSettings section... unusual but evidently possible
            if (targeAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings") == null)
                targeAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration").AppendChild(targeAppConfigDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "appSettings", null));
        }
        private void AddKeyValues(XmlNode configAppNodeSet, ref XmlDocument targetAppConfigDoc)
        {
            if (configAppNodeSet == null) return; // Nothing to do

            foreach (XmlNode configNode in configAppNodeSet.SelectNodes("add"))
            {
                XmlNode targetNode = targetAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='" + configNode.Attributes["key"].Value + "']");
                if (targetNode != null)
                {
                    targetNode.Attributes["value"].Value = configNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
                }
            }
        }
        private void AddRequiredKeys(XmlNode targetAppNodeSet, ref XmlDocument targetAppConfigDoc)
        {
            if (targetAppNodeSet == null) return; // Nothing to do

            foreach (XmlNode targetNode in targetAppNodeSet.SelectNodes("key"))
            {
                // add the key if it doesn't already exist
                XmlNode appNode = targetAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings/add[@key='" + targetNode.Attributes["value"].Value + "']");
                if (appNode == null)
                {
                    appNode = targetAppConfigDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings");
                    XmlNode newAddNode = targetAppConfigDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", null);
                    XmlAttribute newAddNodeKey = targetAppConfigDoc.CreateAttribute("key");
                    newAddNodeKey.Value = targetNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
                    XmlAttribute newAddNodeValue = targetAppConfigDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
                    newAddNodeValue.Value = "NotSet";
                    newAddNode.Attributes.Append(newAddNodeKey);
                    newAddNode.Attributes.Append(newAddNodeValue);
                    appNode.AppendChild(newAddNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of the installation, you can get a lot of this by following a variant of the remember-property pattern. Create a shared component that registers various configuration information in a shared registry key, by storing the values of properties referenced by your XML File Changes. Use system searches to attempt to read these values back into subsequent runs of the same or related installations. However this approach will not update existing separate config files in the related projects.

To address that (though you may find separate configurations to be useful in their own right), I would suggest finding a way to reference a single shared configuration. This might be through using a shared directory for the config file. It might be through referencing a shared registry location directly and skipping the XML File Changes previously described.

Comment: Placing data into registry key's only solves the multiple installation issue for a single machine where I need to share those settings across a number of machines.

Comment: If you want multiple packages and multiple *machines*, you'll need to figure out a way to share the data. Is it a single "primary" server which all others query for configuration? Is it a GPO push of configuration to all the local machines in question? Or do you just have to update all machines?

Comment: <quote>you'll need to figure out a way to share the data.</quote> - per the original question we are going to share via an xml file.

Comment: XML is just a serialization format. How and when will you share this XML file across multiple machines? That's the part that I still can't find in the original question (either mentioned or asked).

Comment: The XML file will be copied into the same directory as the setup.exe. The XML file is such a minor piece of this issue...